# Dynamic-variable sized arrays in matlab

Tags: matlab

This code is working but needs to be improved for efficient calculations

```
anisLoc=[];% Variable sized array
PiezoLoc=[]; % Variable sized array


for i=1:q % Looking in all q
    if ~isempty(LayerProp{i}.c)% if c is not empty then
        anisLoc=[anisLoc,i];
        c{i}=LayerProp{i}.c;
    end
    if ~isempty(LayerProp{i}.e) % if e is not empty then
        %         if LayerProp{i}.e(3,3)
        PiezoLoc=[i;PiezoLoc];
        e{i}=LayerProp{i}.e;
        %         end
    end

end
```

anisLoc and Piezoloc are variable sized arrays. I set them on their maximum values q
but they change size and could not empty them after so they produce same answer from initial code!!

```
anisLoc=zeros(q,1);% Variable sized array
PiezoLoc=zeros(1,q);% Variable sized array

% This loop checks for specific input in data in all 
for i=1:q % Looking in all q
    if ~isempty(LayerProp{i}.c)% if c is not empty
        anisLoc=[i;anisLoc];
        c{i}=LayerProp{i}.c;
    end
    if ~isempty(LayerProp{i}.e) % if e is not empty
        %         if LayerProp{i}.e(3,3)
        PiezoLoc=[PiezoLoc,i];
        e{i}=LayerProp{i}.e;
        %         end
    end

end
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your question here? Do you want to speed up your code? If so, you've taken a good first step with pre-allocation. You could try `profile` to test for bottlenecks in your code.

Comment: @Fraukje: It would be a good first step if the pre-allocation was done right... He creates a zero-vector and adds all new elements to the end of this vector. `anisLoc=[i;anisLoc];` .

Comment: @RobertP. I didn't like into it that well, but now you mention I see it indeed, good job!

Comment: @Fraukje my question is how to use preallocation. I tried to do it but I could not empty the array and the array still grow!

Comment: @RobertP. thanks for the idea I needed to add a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should be quite a bit faster:

```
anisLoc=zeros(q,1);% Variable sized array
PiezoLoc=zeros(1,q);% Variable sized array

% This loop checks for specific input in data in all 
k = 0;
m = 0;
for ii=1:q % Looking in all q
    if ~isempty(LayerProp{ii}.c)% if c is not empty
        k = k + 1;
        anisLoc(k)=ii;
        c{ii}=LayerProp{ii}.c;
    end
    if ~isempty(LayerProp{ii}.e) % if e is not empty
        %         if LayerProp{ii}.e(3,3)
        m = m + 1;
        PiezoLoc(m) = ii;
        e{ii}=LayerProp{ii}.e;
        %         end
    end

anisLoc(k+1:end) = [];
PiezoLoc(m+1:end) = [];

end
```

Comment: I believe you meant k+1 at third line from bottom i.e.:

anisLoc(k+1:end) = [];
PiezoLoc(m+1:end) = [];

end

Comment: @drx: If this answer was satisfactory, could you please consider accepting it? Thanks!